# error while importing geojson in vite.js + react

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, vite, geojson, react-map-gl

I'm trying to import an auto-generated geojson file from [openlab](http://opendatalab.de/projects/geojson-utilities/) into App.js, however, I'm receiving an error while trying to console.log() the file. Did I miss something?

Error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at gemeinden_simplify200.geojson?t=1706820513765&import:1:8)`

My Code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import Map, { Source, Layer } from "react-map-gl";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import GeoData from "./assets/gemeinden_simplify200.geojson";
import { dataLayer } from "./assets/map_style";

function App() {
  const [year, setYear] = useState(2010);

  const token = "***";

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Map
        mapboxAccessToken={token}
        initialViewState={{
          latitude: 40,
          longitude: -100,
          zoom: 3,
        }}
        style={{ width: 600, height: 400 }}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
      >
        <Source type="geojson" data={GeoData}>
          <Layer {...dataLayer} />
        </Source>
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to convert the file into .json, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I think the error is in the GeoJson file. Maybe double quotes issue. See if the error goes away when you remove some of the data in that file.